# Larmor precession, different component of magnetic field and base of matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

I'm currently stuck with a question involving what I think is sort of the Larmor precession. I have an electron in a uniform, magnetic field pointing in the $x$-axis and I'm supposed to calculate the eigenstate of $S_z$ at time $t$.

I'm trying to follow an example in Griffiths book but I'm running into a problem with $S_z$ and the magnetic field. The hamiltonian is defined as, for this problem, $H=-k\,B\cdot S$ where $B\cdot S$ denotes a dot product. This dot product is $0$ since they are perpendicular to each other, how should I confront this problem?

Comment: You need to realise that $S$ is an operator, not just a vector.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294228/154997

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300327/154997

Comment: One more: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233873/154997

Comment: I'm extremely slowly picking up those kind of things, I know that the matrix representation is rather an operator in the Hilbertspace, but I still don't know how to start on this problem...

Comment: There is obviously a lot in this question that I do not understand, but my main concern right now is how to apply the magnetic field currently in x-direction instead of the z-direction (which would have been easier to work with)

Comment: Under the given hypotheses, your Hamiltonian is $H=-kBS_x$. Now in the basis $(|+1>,|-1>)$ of the eigenvectors of $S_z$, the operator $S_x$ has a well-known matrix. Once you have written it down, you can diagonalise it to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$.  Then you can evolve any initial state.

Comment: Im sorry for all the questions, but how do I know that since the eigenvectors of Sz does span Sx, then I can just as well use the Sx operator, which is exactly what I want, but why is that okay? Thanks again for all the help, appreciated!

Comment: You mean using a basis of eigenstate for $S_x$ as a starter? Sure, you can do that and then the eigenvalues and eigenstate of $H$ immediately follow. Now let's say you start from the eigenstate $|+\rangle$ of $S_z$: you then need to write it in the basis of the eigenstates of $S_x$, where you know how to evolve them since you've diagonalised $H$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magnetic susceptibility for spin-1 particle - magnetic moment and field interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300327/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Particle with spin in uniform magnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294228/particle-with-spin-in-uniform-magnetic-field)

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

> This dot product is $0$ since they are perpendicular to each other.

While the *expected* value of the spin might lie along the $z$ axis, the spin is still a vector-valued operator, which means that when contracted with the regular vector $\mathbf B$ you're left with the linear combination
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathbf S}\cdot\mathbf B
=
\hat{S}_xB_x+\hat{S}_yB_y+\hat{S}_zB_z,
\end{align}
and that's an operator since the $\hat{S}_i$ are operators and the $B_i$ are numbers.

This then gives you your hamiltonian, and you just work the time evolution like you would with any arbitrary hamiltonian.

in your specific case $\mathbf B$ is along $x$, which means that $\hat H = - kB\hat S_x$. If you want to work in the $S_z$ eigenbasis, that hamiltonian has the matrix representation
$$
\hat H = - kB\hat S_x
=-kB\frac12 \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}. 
 $$
For further details, refer to your textbook.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, right now I'm basically trying to understand why I can use the matrix Sx when I have spinn "in z direction". What part of the theory haven't I understood?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you mean by "the Sx matrix". If you mean its diagonal form, then no, that's inappropriate. However, you can represent *any* spin component, along an arbitrary direction, as a non-diagonal matrix in the Sz basis. (or you can work in the Sx eigenbasis, in which case the hamiltonian is diagonal but your initial state is a superposition of basis states.) If any of that sounds confusing, you probably need to go back to the textbook.

Comment: I'm working with Grifiths book currently, trying to read up what everything means, I'm a bit confused, not going to lie, is there a way you could give me an example if I wanted to represent a spin component, for example in x-direction, with the Sz basis?